# Error C2144 and Error C4430 on the same line

Tags: c++

I am working on the "battle of wesnoth" code for an assignment.
Today while compiling it I got the following errors (I didn't receive these errors when I compiled the project before):

The code is (its a .hpp file):

```
/* $Id: pathfind.hpp 54806 2012-07-20 22:17:33Z jamit $ */
/*
   Copyright (C) 2003 - 2012 by David White <dave@whitevine.net>
   Part of the Battle for Wesnoth Project http://www.wesnoth.org/

   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.
   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY.

   See the COPYING file for more details.
*/

/**
 * @file
 * This module contains various pathfinding functions and utilities.
 */

#ifndef PATHFIND_H_INCLUDED
#define PATHFIND_H_INCLUDED

class gamemap;
class team;
class unit;
class unit_map;
class unit_movement_type;

#include "map_location.hpp"

#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

namespace pathfind {

class teleport_map;

enum VACANT_TILE_TYPE { VACANT_CASTLE, VACANT_ANY };
enum PATH_TYPE { MOVE, VISION, JAMMING };

/// Function that will find a location on the board that is as near
/// to @a loc as possible, but which is unoccupied by any units.
map_location find_vacant_tile(const map_location& loc,
                              VACANT_TILE_TYPE vacancy=VACANT_ANY,
                              const unit* pass_check=NULL,
                              const team* shroud_check=NULL);
/// Wrapper for find_vacant_tile() when looking for a vacant castle tile
/// near a leader.
map_location find_vacant_castle(const unit & leader);

/** Determines if a given location is in an enemy zone of control. */
bool enemy_zoc(team const &current_team, map_location const &loc,
               team const &viewing_team, bool see_all=false);


struct cost_calculator
{
    cost_calculator() {}

    virtual double cost(const map_location& loc, const double so_far) const = 0;
    virtual ~cost_calculator() {}

    static double getNoPathValue() { return (42424242.0); }
};

/**
 * Object which contains all the possible locations a unit can move to,
 * with associated best routes to those locations.
 */
struct paths
{
    paths()
        : destinations()
    {
    }

    /// Construct a list of paths for the specified unit.
    paths(gamemap const &map,
          unit_map const &/*units*/, // Not used
          const unit& u, std::vector<team> const &teams,
          bool force_ignore_zocs, bool allow_teleport,
          const team &viewing_team, int additional_turns = 0,
          bool see_all = false, bool ignore_units = false);
    /// Virtual destructor (default processing).
    virtual ~paths();

    struct step
    {
        map_location curr, prev;
        int move_left;
    };

    /** Ordered vector of possible destinations. */
    struct dest_vect : std::vector<step>
    {
        const_iterator find(const map_location &) const;
        bool contains(const map_location &) const;
        void insert(const map_location &);
        std::vector<map_location> get_path(const const_iterator &) const;
    };
    dest_vect destinations;
};

/**
 * A refinement of paths for use when calculating vision.
 */
struct vision_path : public paths
{
    /// Construct a list of seen hexes for a unit.
    vision_path(gamemap const &map, const unit& viewer,
                map_location const &loc, const std::map<map_location, int>& jamming_map);
    virtual ~vision_path();

    /// The edges are the non-destination hexes bordering the destinations.
    std::set<map_location> edges;
};

/**
 * A refinement of paths for use when calculating jamming.
 */
struct jamming_path : public paths
{
    /// Construct a list of jammed hexes for a unit.
    jamming_path(gamemap const &map, const unit& jammer,
                map_location const &loc);
    virtual ~jamming_path();

    /// The edges are the non-destination hexes bordering the destinations.
    //std::set<map_location> edges;
};


/** Structure which holds a single route between one location and another. */
struct plain_route
{
    plain_route() : steps(), move_cost(0) {}
    std::vector<map_location> steps;
    /** Movement cost for reaching the end of the route. */
    int move_cost;
};

/** Structure which holds a single route and marks for special events. */
struct marked_route
{
    marked_route()
        : route()
        , steps(route.steps)
        , move_cost(route.move_cost)
        , marks()
    {
    }

    marked_route(const marked_route& rhs)
        : route(rhs.route)
        , steps(route.steps)
        , move_cost(route.move_cost)
        , marks(rhs.marks)
    {
    }

    marked_route& operator=(const marked_route& rhs)
    {
        this->route = rhs.route;
        this->steps = this->route.steps;
        this->move_cost = this->route.move_cost;
        this->marks = rhs.marks;
        return *this;
    }

    struct mark
    {
        mark(int turns_number = 0, bool in_zoc = false,
                bool do_capture = false, bool is_invisible = false)
            : turns(turns_number), zoc(in_zoc),
              capture(do_capture), invisible(is_invisible) {}
        int turns;
        bool zoc;
        bool capture;
        bool invisible;

        bool operator==(const mark& m) const {
            return turns == m.turns && zoc == m.zoc && capture == m.capture && invisible == m.invisible;
        }
    };
    typedef std::map<map_location, mark> mark_map;
    plain_route route;

    //make steps and move_cost of the underlying plain_route directly accessible
    std::vector<map_location>& steps;
    int& move_cost;

    mark_map marks;
};

plain_route a_star_search(map_location const &src, map_location const &dst,
        double stop_at, const cost_calculator* costCalculator,
        const size_t parWidth, const size_t parHeight,
        const teleport_map* teleports = NULL);

/**
 * Add marks on a route @a rt assuming that the unit located at the first hex of
 * rt travels along it.
 */
marked_route mark_route(const plain_route &rt);

struct shortest_path_calculator : cost_calculator
{
    shortest_path_calculator(const unit& u, const team& t, const unit_map& units,
        const std::vector<team> &teams, const gamemap &map,
        bool ignore_unit = false, bool ignore_defense_ = false,
        bool see_all = false);
    virtual double cost(const map_location& loc, const double so_far) const;

private:
    unit const &unit_;
    team const &viewing_team_;
    unit_map const &units_;
    std::vector<team> const &teams_;
    gamemap const &map_;
    int const movement_left_;
    int const total_movement_;
    bool const ignore_unit_;
    bool const ignore_defense_;
    bool see_all_;
};

struct move_type_path_calculator : cost_calculator
{
    move_type_path_calculator(const unit_movement_type& mt, int movement_left, int total_movement, const team& t, const gamemap& map);
    virtual double cost(const map_location& loc, const double so_far) const;

private:
    const unit_movement_type &movement_type_;
    const int movement_left_;
    const int total_movement_;
    team const &viewing_team_;
    gamemap const &map_;
};

/**
 * Function which only uses terrain, ignoring shroud, enemies, etc.
 * Required by move_unit_fake if the normal path fails.
 */
struct emergency_path_calculator : cost_calculator
{
    emergency_path_calculator(const unit& u, const gamemap& map);
    virtual double cost(const map_location& loc, const double so_far) const;

private:
    unit const &unit_;
    gamemap const &map_;
};

/**
 * Function which doesn't take anything into account. Used by
 * move_unit_fake for the last-chance case.
 */
struct dummy_path_calculator : cost_calculator
{
    dummy_path_calculator(const unit& u, const gamemap& map);
    virtual double cost(const map_location& loc, const double so_far) const;
};

}

#endif
```

The errors:

> c:\users...\trunk\wesnoth-1.11.0\src\pathfind\pathfind.hpp(24): **error C2144: syntax error : 'gamemap' should be preceded by ';'**
>   1>c:\users...s\trunk\wesnoth-1.11.0\src\pathfind\pathfind.hpp(24): **error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int**

Comment: Your function bodies don't need a semicolon after them, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Check the header(s) you include before this one in all places you include this file.

One of them will end with a class/struct which is missing the final semicolon:

```
class Foo
{
}  // <-- missing semicolon here is not picked up until
   //     the next declaration in another file
```

Add the semicolon and call it a day :-)

Comment: I am a little confused here.
Basically what you are trying to say is, I should check all the files that includes "pathfind.hpp" and check whether ';' is missing?

Comment: @user: Not quite. I'm saying that somewhere you do `#include "blah.h" #include... #include "pathfind.hpp"`. Because the preprocessor expands the entire contents of include files inline, if there was a missing semicolon at the end of the last declaration *inside "blah.h"*, the compiler wouldn't pick it up until the next line of code it processes, which happens in this case to be in "pathfind.hpp". Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes.. it makes so much more sense.. Oh well.. it's going to take me a LONG LONG time.. there are a lot of places where 'pathfind.hpp' is included. 
And one more question.. Is is the header file just before 'pathfind.hpp' [wherever they are included]?

Comment: @user: Well, if things were working until recently, it's going to be in a file that you just changed/added. It will be included before 'pathfind.hpp', but not necessarily immediately before, since headers that were already included (directly or indirectly) by earlier other headers get skipped (because of include guards/#pragma once).